# R quanteda dfm grouping does not work for all docvars

Tags: r, grouping, quanteda

I have a dataframe ("PostsRaw") containing documents (=Facebook Posts) from different Persons on different dates. 
After making a corpus() and a dfm() of that dataframe i wanted to group within the dfm using the dfm_group() function.

```
Corpus1 <- corpus(PostsRaw)
Corpus1DFM <- dfm(Corpus1)
dfmDatumGroup <- dfm_group(Corpus1DFM, groups = colnames(docvars(Corpus1DFM))[3])
```

[image: corpus information]

I can group perfectly fine over the third docvar named "Datum" (both as factor or date) and over all docvars that are integer, but i am not able to group over the 2 first variables "Poltiker" (=the name) and "Partei" (=political party), both when factor or character.

```
dfmPoltikerGroup <- dfm_group(Corpus1DFM, groups = colnames(docvars(Corpus1DFM))[1])
```

with those two i get the error:

```
Error in x[as.character(levels(groups)), ] : Subscript out of bounds
```

I tried the additional arguments fill and force without success.

Does anybody have an idea, why the first two variables dont work, altough they seem to be the in a fitting type?

Comment: Have you tried this with the just-published quanteda v2? Also: This is more of an issue, not a SO question.

Comment: No i havent and the update is failing. I thought i may be missing something obvious and thus the questions.

Comment: I’m happy to test if you file a github issue and supply enough info or data so that the error can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Both docvars that caused the error had Values/Factors with Umlaute Ü/Ä/Ö in it. Replacing them with UE etc. solved it.